# Alternative to imrpot directive

Tags: visual-c++

ALL,

Is there an alternative to `#import` directive on MSVC?

I'm trying to load DAO dll, but it looks like it could be installed in a different location.

And I can't use it inside the function code - MSVC errors out.

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

DAO has been deprecated for a number of years now, and is not available in 64-bit at all.

In 32-bit the following compiles fine with VC++ 2019 (though, again, DAO is not recommended for new development).

```
#import <C:\program files (x86)\common files\microsoft shared\dao\dao360.dll> rename("EOF", "daoEOF")
```

Comment: what is an alternative? How do I access DB from C++?

Comment: @Igor Main general-purpose choices are ODBC, OLE DB or ADO. You'll find some pointers at [Data Access in Visual C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/data/data-access-in-cpp?view=msvc-160). Also, the answer to [Migrating from obsolete DAO classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718560/migrating-from-obsolete-dao-classes) is still fairly current.

Comment: I'm using ODBC, but wanted to get a ACCESS version that made the DB file. Got suggestion to use DAO. probably ADO is best choice, right?

Comment: @Igor That should work, see also the [ADOX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/adox-api/adox-object-model?view=sql-server-ver15) ActiveX Data Objects Extensions for Data Definition Language and Security.